# Connotation of "intestinal fortitude"

Tags: meaning, expressions

I have heard the expression *intestinal fortitude* to mean courage or endurance to achieve something. Is there a connotation for stubbornness in this expression?

Comment: You really should give us where this question came from. Did someone say something that implied stubbornness?

Comment: No, it's just a euphemism for *guts*. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intestinal%20fortitude

Comment: I don't think its guts exactly. It seems to be both guts (i.e. courage) and the ability to stick it out during difficult/undesirable situations.

Comment: @Jeremy Do you have the intestinal fortitude to expound your theory in an answer?

Comment: Jeremy, you're wrong. "intestinal fortitude" is precisely, exactly, indeed - literally - a funny way to say "guts".  You know what "intestines" are right?  z7sg is correct.

Comment: I wouldn't say Jeremy's wrong in saying it includes "the ability to stick it out during difficult/undesirable situations"; rather that "guts" already has this sense, as well as courage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments, *[intestinal fortitude](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intestinal%20fortitude)* can be called a euphemism for guts. [Guts](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guts) is defined as "*fortitude and stamina in coping with what alarms, repels, or discourages*", or [by Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3a%20guts#hl=en&q=gut&tbs=dfn:1&fp=1) as "*personal courage and determination; toughness of character*".

Both definitions have some mention of tenacity - "stamina" implies an ability to go on without giving up, and "determination" implies willingness not to give up. Similarly, "stubbornness" implies a refusal to give up. Thus I think there are similarities, although "intestinal fortitude" - or "guts" - seems to include the positive side of "stubborn", and not its possible negative connotations.

As a clarification, I am not saying that "guts" connotes "stubborn", nor vice versa, but that both those words strongly connote "tenacity", and in that way there is a link between them.

Comment: @z7sg: I was going to do that... Is there really a limit on the links according to reputation?

Comment: @Alenannon At 10 rep there is, I thought it was one link, though he posted two somehow!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like 'tenacity' in your explanation, I think it fits well with what I was expecting.

Comment: You say **""stubbornness" implies a refusal to give up"** - that is simply not correct.  Stubborn is a refusal to change. It's that simple.  If you have guts, you can take part in fist-fights, eat nails, etc.  Really there's no relationship to stubbornness.

Comment: @Joe Blow Well, yes, but I was speaking with regards to a chosen path. Sure, it takes guts to eat nails, but that includes not giving up eating nails after they start to hurt your mouth. That could be out of stubbornness. Giving up is changing your mind, and thus is covered by stubbornness. It just so happens that being stubborn can mean more than that, which is why there are similarities between the connotations of being stubborn and having guts, within some situations. Hence me saying they're similar, but far from identical.

Comment: @SamThere - not really, no.  You're now saying that: having guts could perhaps be *caused* by being stubborn ...  etc etc **As z7sg pointed out immediately when the question was posed**, it is **just a euphemism for guts**.  It really is just that simple.

Comment: @Joe Blow Yes, it's a euphemism for guts, and it is that simple. But then it follows to consider whether there's any connotations of stubbornness in this meaning of guts, and I said that while neither really implies the other, they both have common implication of tenacity in many of their potential uses. A situation in which a person could be described as "gutsy" - by virtue of *stamina* or *determination* - would most likely be a situation where that person could instead (from a slightly different viewpoint) be described as "stubborn", by virtue of *refusal to change* their course of action.

Comment: @Joe Blow Additionally, "implies" doesn't mean the same as "means". A "refusal to change" would imply a "refusal to give up" a course of action, since giving up would be a change.

Comment: @Joe-Blow Do I tag you @ Joe Blow or @ Joe-Blow? :P

Comment: @Sam, I believe simply Joe will work, cheers.  In any event a space will **not** work, omit spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the answer is simply "no".

Stubborn quite simply means someone who won't change their mind.

(Or indeed, something like say a piece of metal you have to machine could be "stubborn" - hard to change it's shape.)

This quality, stubborn, has nothing to do with "having guts" - like Tom Cruise or John Wayne. If you have guts, you can crawl through swamps, fight nazis, etc.

There's really no relation to "stubborn".

Particularly if the questioner is a non-English speaker, wondering what the phrase means, it's a shame to confuse the questioner.

Quite simply, "intestinal fortitude" is a **humorous alternate way to say the slang term "guts"**. (Like, a street fighter, etc.) No real connection to stubborn.

Answer (score 1):

There's more to it, I think... "guts"is a reference to the intestines, which run from the pyloris (at the end of the stomach) to the anus, and, "guts" also is a euphemism for "toughness" or "courage".

The phrase, "intestinal fortitude" takes this one step further, with implications of tenacity and toughness under fire - in dangerous situations, people can lose their nerve, turn tail and run, and in so doing, their fear can even cause them to lose control of their anal sphincter, with the expected result. Someone with "intestinal fortitude" has mastered their fear instinct AND their sphincter, and when the going gets tough, they have the self control to override their animal instinct to **** themselves and run away, and so can stand their ground and prevail.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks that are difficult and unpleasant are sometimes said to be "stomach churning," that is making people want to throw up.

People that can performing "stomach churning" task without giving up, and without throwing up, are said to have **intestinal fortitude.**

I wouldn't characterize this as "stubbornness," but possibly as "perseverance."